# Modify all classes at once in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to modify all the .cs files including classes and code-behind files.
I want to add [serializable] attribute to all .cs files at one.

I don't want to open individual class and update, because there are hundreds of .cs files in my project solution.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you need *all* your classes to be serializable?

Comment: Possibly a global find/replace would work, but it's unlikely that you really want to apply this to *every* class...

Comment: Have you tried a find and replace against the entire solution?

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea... Most classes don't need to be serializable (and for many of them it wouldn't make any sense)

Comment: @DanPuzey Might work, like replace `public class` with `[Serializable()] public class`. Not sure how to do a wildcard in find & replace to deal with different access modifiers.

Comment: Find & Replace I know, but then it would open all files in visual studio in unsaved mode, sometimes it hangs the whole application and closes visual studio.

Comment: @ShailendrasinhParmar Eh? Never heard of find & replace crashing visual studio.

Comment: @ShailendrasinhParmar: that feature is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do a find and replace against the entire solution, just search for 'public class ' and replace with '[Serializable()] public class '. You'd then just need to do the same for 'private ', 'internal ', 'static ' classes etc. in the same way...

Comment: If you check `Use Regular Expressions` under `Find options` you can replace with `[Serializable()]\n\tpublic class` so the attribute is on the previous line instead